# Disable a Multibranch Pipeline in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl, multibranch-pipeline

A MBP is created when I run a Seed-job that fetches a groovy file from the filesystem. Now, when I rename a project on gitlab, the groovy script gets updated with the required changes and creates a new MBP on Jenkins when I re-run the seed-job.

Is there a way I can disable the previous MBP once the new one is created. I do have a option to disable MBP manually, but can this be done automatically?

Any suggestions on how can the old-MBP be disabled automatically?

Comment: Do you want to disable it or remove? The post title is different than the question in the description.

Comment: Disable the MBP automatically. Sorry.

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to disable it instead of removing? Removing option is provided by the Job DSL plugin OOTB.